# How to evaluate if a environment variable is set in vimrc

Tags: function, vim

How to evaluate if an bash environment variable is set

for example

```
function! Myfoo(arg)
  if $SomeVar is set/exist ----> how to eval the SomeVar has been set
     ....
  endif
endfunction
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You've (intuitively?) used the correct syntax; as [`:help expression-syntax`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#expression-syntax) explains (under [`:help expr-env`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#expr-env)), the syntax is `$VAR`.

You can compare with an empty string (`if $SomeVar != ""`) or use `empty()` (`if !empty($SomeVar)`) to check whether a (non-empty) value has been supplied. It's not so easy to differentiate between empty environment variable and non-existing environment variable, so this is best avoided. (This distinction also is rarely used in shell scripts itself, neither.)

Example:

```
# vi ~/.vimrc
if !empty($vim_background)
   :let &background = $vim_background
endif
```

Comment: Could you please add an exemple : if the env variable `vim_background` is defined, then `: set background=$vim_background` ?

Comment: @MUYBelgium The `:set` command is special in that the value is taken literally. You'd have to interpolate the (Vim or environment) variable via `:execute 'set background=' . $vim_background`, but fortunately the `:let` command (which unlike `:set` supports Vim expressions at the right-hand side) has a special form (`:help :let-option`) that addresses Vim options: `:let &background = $vim_background`